# macOS gpg decryption permission denied

Tags: mac, encryption, gpg

I'm encountering an issue with GPG decryption when I try to decrypt a file with:

`gpg -decrypt filename.gpg`

I receive the following error messages:

```
gpg: public key decryption failed: Permission denied 
gpg: decryption failed: Permission denied
```

could somebody help me please

Comment: What is the permission on the file, and on the keyring?